# Kafka Connect sink to Redshift table not in public schema

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I am unable to make a Kafka Connect sink work for a table that is not in the public schema.

I am using Kafka Connect to send records to a Redshift database via a sink operation using JdbcSinkConnector.

I have created my destination table in Redshift, but it is not in the `public` schema. (`my_schema.test_table`. Note: `auto.create` & `auto.evolve` are off in the connector configuration)

When I attempt to specify the table's location in the connector config, like so...

`"table.name.format": "my_schema.test_table",`

...the sink connector's task encounters this error when it attempts to get itself going:

**"Table my_schema.test_table is missing and auto-creation is disabled"**

from

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table my_schema.test_table is missing and auto-creation is disabled
  at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:86)
  at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:63)
  at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:78)
  ...`

I have tried the following formats for supplying table name:

- `my_schema.test_table`
- `dev.my_schema.test_table`
- `test_table` <-- in this case I get past the existence check that stops the others, but then run into this error every time Kafka Connect attempts to write a row:

  - "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Amazon Invalid operation: relation "test_table" does not exist;"
  - Likely because `test_table` is not in the public schema. : (

And it *seems* like the code is attempting to parse this table name correctly, but unfortunately it doesn't log its results.

This is my connection string: `"connection.url": "jdbc:redshift://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5439/dev"`

I have mucked around with attempting so specify `currentSchema=my_schema` in the connection string... both for the `redshift` jdbc driver as well as `postgresql`. No luck.

I'm using Kafka Connect version 1.1.0

Redshift JDBC JAR: `RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.16.1027.jar`

I am able to get data flowing by putting the table in the `public` schema and specifying table name with no schema: `"table.name.format": "test_table"`.
Unfortunately, that's not where we need the data to be.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the source code seemed to be trying to do the right thing… and then realized that the version of the JDBC sink connector we were using did not have those modifications, which are somewhat recent. I moved from version 4.1.0 of the JDBC sink connector jar to version 5.0.0 and voila data is flowing into a table in the schema I specified.